# How to filter and copy a value in R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, dplyr

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
Test <- c('Sodium','Heamo Index.','Lipae Index','ictoric index','Chloride','Blood pressure','Test Index')
value <- c(12,'No haemo',NA,'No ict',21,32,NA)
TextualResults <- c('low value',NA,'NO LIPA',NA,'HIGH','low','NO TEST')

df_test <- data.frame(Test,value,TextualResults)
```

The **input** looks like as shown below

[image]

I was trying something like this

```
library(tidyverse)

df_test %>%  
  filter(stringr::str_detect(type, 'index|Index|INDEX'))
```

But not sure how to copy the value based on `NA` check and make the search case-insensitive in a elegant way

I expect **my output** to be like as shown below

[image]

As you can see that under `Test` column, whenever we find values which contain `index` (case insensitive), we have to make sure that `value` column is not `NA` for those rows.

Data by default might have value for `index` rows under `value` column but it could be `NA` as well.

So, when it's `NA` we pick whatever value is present under `TextualResults` column and put it back in `value` column for rows containing `index` term. Basically `value` column will never be `NA` for rows containing `index` term

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could try:

```
library(dplyr)

df_test %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>% # or mutate_at(-1, as.character) if you'd like to keep first as factor
  mutate(
    value = case_when(
      grepl('index', Test, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ coalesce(value, TextualResults),
      TRUE ~ value
    )
  )
```

Output:

```
            Test    value TextualResults
1         Sodium       12      low value
2    Heamo Index No haemo           <NA>
3    Lipae Index  NO LIPA        NO LIPA
4  ictoric index   No ict           <NA>
5       Chloride       21           HIGH
6 Blood pressure       32            low
7     Test Index  NO TEST        NO TEST
```

This should work on all combinations of index, regardless whether it is preceeded or succeeded by a dot, other characters, upper/lower case, etc.

Consider this:

```
Test <- c('Sodium','Heamo Index.','Lipae Index..','ictoric __index','Chloride','Blood pressure','Test $$Index')
value <- c(12,'No haemo',NA,NA,21,32,NA)
TextualResults <- c('low value',NA,'NO LIPA','No ict','HIGH','low','NO TEST')

df_test <- data.frame(Test,value,TextualResults)

             Test    value TextualResults
1          Sodium       12      low value
2    Heamo Index. No haemo           <NA>
3   Lipae Index..     <NA>        NO LIPA
4 ictoric __index     <NA>         No ict
5        Chloride       21           HIGH
6  Blood pressure       32            low
7    Test $$Index     <NA>        NO TEST
```

Output with the above code:

```
             Test    value TextualResults
1          Sodium       12      low value
2    Heamo Index. No haemo           <NA>
3   Lipae Index..  NO LIPA        NO LIPA
4 ictoric __index   No ict         No ict
5        Chloride       21           HIGH
6  Blood pressure       32            low
7    Test $$Index  NO TEST        NO TEST
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted. Does `-1` indicate column position? what does it indicate?

Comment: It indicates that you are mutating at all columns except the first one - so indeed, it indicates the position.

Comment: Okay, q1) so it's like you convert all columns to character and then apply the case_when condition. q2) by `~ coalesce (value, TextualResults), do you copy data value from `Textual results column to `value` column? q3) what does `TRUE ~value` do?

Comment: q1 ) Indeed, q2) `coalesce` looks at both columns and takes the non-missing value, 3) `TRUE` is equivalent to `else` in `ifelse`, i.e. it looks at all rows other than those containing `index` in any form (and just keeps them as they are, i.e. as initial `value`

Comment: Will this solution work if I don't convert everything to characeter? As I am dealing with a million records dataframe, just wondering whether it would be wise to change the datatype.

Comment: You'll need to convert at least the `value` and `TextualResults`, otherwise no, it won't work

Comment: But converting to character will not result in any loss of data. Am I right? Even though it's numeric/alphanumeric etc>

Comment: No, converting to character is one of the safest conversions you can do

Comment: Does this consider if it's `index.`, meaning if there is a dot at the end of index? I see those terms are being ignored?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207662/discussion-between-arg0naut91-and-the-great).

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
# Change value and TextualResults from factor to character
df_test[-1] <- lapply(df_test[-1], as.character)


df_test <- 
  df_test %>% 
  mutate(value = if_else(grepl("Index", Test, ignore.case = TRUE) & is.na(value), TextualResults, value))

df_test
            Test    value TextualResults
1         Sodium       12      low value
2    Heamo Index No haemo           <NA>
3    Lipae Index  NO LIPA        NO LIPA
4  ictoric index   No ict           <NA>
5       Chloride       21           HIGH
6 Blood pressure       32            low
7     Test Index  NO TEST        NO TEST
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted. `-1` indicates what?

Comment: Does this also consider it it's "index." meaning with a dot... My terms can be like " haemolysis index." or like "icteric index"

Comment: What about "." at the end of index?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207737/discussion-between-the-great-and-sindri-baldur).

Answer (score 1):

I would use `if_else()` to accomplish this. I make it into a tibble rather than data frame at first to avoid factors.

```
Test <- c('Sodium','Heamo Index','Lipae Index','ictoric index','Chloride','Blood pressure','Test Index')
value <- c(12,'No haemo',NA,'No ict',21,32,NA)
TextualResults <- c('low value',NA,'NO LIPA',NA,'HIGH','low','NO TEST')
df_test <- tibble(Test,value,TextualResults)

contains_index <- str_detect(df_test$Test, 'index|Index|INDEX')

new_df <-
  df_test %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(is.na(value) & contains_index, TextualResults, value))
```

Comment: sure, I think it works the same as a data frame pretty much: https://tibble.tidyverse.org/. My code would also work with a data frame as long as the columns are a character and not factors.

Answer (score 1):

```
df_test %>%
   mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(value) & Test %like% 'index|Index|INDEX', as.character(TextualResults), as.character(value)))
            Test    value TextualResults
1         Sodium       12      low value
2   Heamo Index. No haemo           <NA>
3    Lipae Index  NO LIPA        NO LIPA
4  ictoric index   No ict           <NA>
5       Chloride       21           HIGH
6 Blood pressure       32            low
7     Test Index  NO TEST        NO TEST
```

Let's modify it a bit:

```
Test <- c('Sodium','Heamo ..Index..','Lipae .Index_','ictoric ?index  ','Chloride','Blood pressure','Test Index')
value <- c(12,'No haemo',NA,'No ict',21,32,NA)
TextualResults <- c('low value',NA,'NO LIPA',NA,'HIGH','low','NO TEST')
df_test <- data.frame(Test,value,TextualResults)

df_test
              Test    value TextualResults
1           Sodium       12      low value
2  Heamo ..Index.. No haemo           <NA>
3    Lipae .Index_     <NA>        NO LIPA
4 ictoric ?index     No ict           <NA>
5         Chloride       21           HIGH
6   Blood pressure       32            low
7       Test Index     <NA>        NO TEST
```

Result is the same:

```
              Test    value TextualResults
1           Sodium       12      low value
2  Heamo ..Index.. No haemo           <NA>
3    Lipae .Index_  NO LIPA        NO LIPA
4 ictoric ?index     No ict           <NA>
5         Chloride       21           HIGH
6   Blood pressure       32            low
7       Test Index  NO TEST        NO TEST
```

Comment: Hi Adamm, thanks for the response. Upvoted.  Does it also consider "index." or "index " or " index". Meaning it can contain spaces or dot like shown in my sample

Comment: I think that `%like%` will take all index types into account, no matter of dots or spaces, such as `grep` mentioned in other answers. Unless you have something like `in.dex', then it might be a problem.

Comment: I put some additional characters around index.

Comment: `%like%` is a wrapper for `grep`, not exactly a distinct function. It works just the same, except that you cannot ignore the case. Not sure why OP is seeing issues where there are none.